# sql database Availability constraint

Tags: mysql, database-design, mysql-workbench

[image]

I am trying to build a database.
A constraint i have to build in, is that an instrument can only be used by one person at a time. my question is how would i implement this?

I have created a AvailableInstrument Table. which draws from a view which takes all of the instruments that have a hire end date < now()

but i don't know how I would implement the constraint in this database model.

Please help :D

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Im using MysqlWorkbench

Comment: MySQL Workbench is not a DBMS, it's a client tool. But I assume you are using MySQL then.

Comment: oops. ur right I'm using mysql. its a school assignment so I'm just building the database and querying it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To this task I can create a InstrumentType domain table with all possible instruments types. A Instrument table with all instruments and a Rent table to hold each time a instrument is hired.
You can use the rent table for historical records and of course you cannot put that constraint here. The simplest way is to get sure a instrument cannot be hired by two musicians is to create a nullable column at Instrument to FK to the actual musician using it.
Another thing to help it is create a returned_datetime column with a default value at that rent table and a unique index covering it and instrument Id to get sure there are only one instrumentId at that default return date.